# Flutter webview plugin disable pop ups

Tags: android, ios, webview, flutter

I want to user webview to load an embed video "https://openload.co/embed/jth7dlXpS9o/48726236_1799258073534949_6159238421089878016_n.mp4" for example.
But when I touch the play button the ads open new web pages or popups. How can i disable the pop up pages?
I was trying with onStateChanged and onUrlChanged events but I still have problems.
Can you give an advice or help, thanks

Comment: what sort of things have you tried? Can you give us any specific code and how the output is different from what you expect?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter), pop-ups can be prevented by blocking redirect requests when the url is being loaded. Utilizing the package's WebViewController, the url can be blocked on `onNavigationRequest`.

```dart
WebViewController webViewController = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update ProgressBar
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('$BLOCKED_URL_PATTERN')) {
            // Prevent blocked URL from loading on WebView
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('$INITIAL_URL'));
```

Then use the controller on the WebView.

```dart
WebViewWidget(controller: webViewController)
```